# Automatic login for mysql used in CGI script

Tags: apache-httpd, mysql, autologin, cgi

I have written a `CGI` script using `bash` which executes a `MySQL` query. For MySQL authentication , automatic login is used by supplying the credentials in .my.cnf file as shown below .

```
# the following section will be read by *all* client programs
[client]
user=dbuser
password=password
```

Since the CGI program is executed as apache user , I placed the .my.cnf under apache's home directory.

```
  # grep apache /etc/passwd
  apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin

 # ls -l /var/www/.my.cnf
 -rw------- 1 apache apache 97 Apr 23 12:36 /var/www/.my.cnf
```

But looks like this is not working as mysql query is not getting executed . I am confused actually where to put the .my.cnf so that mysql query in CGI script can read it from that location.

Code snippet for the script is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo "<html>"
echo "<body>"

mysql -h 192.168.2.140 -D mysql -e "select User from mysql;"

echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
```

Comment: I am not getting any response , please help to migrate this question to "stack overflow".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--defaults-extra-file` argument to mysql to specify the cnf file for it to use:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=/var/www/.my.cnf -h 192.168.2.140 -D mysql -e "select User from mysql;"
```